# creating sounds with createSound(); without errors

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

im trying to create a sound with `createSound();` and this is my code

```
function preload(){
  s = createAudio('sound.wav')
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  s.play();
}
function draw(){
  background(0, 0, 0);
}
```

and this is the error

> p5.js:60546 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined
> at p5.js:60546

i have tried defining the variable before and i have tried having a delay before i play the sound but it shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

1.Did you declare variable s before you put that within preload()?
2.Have you tried "getAudioContext().resume()"? for playing the audio?
3.If what you tried to achieve is 'playing' the audio file, have you tried loadSound() instead of createAudio?